# Alamofire upload JSON response not compiling

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

I'm doing an Alamofire upload to the server and want to decode some JSON that's sent back in response.

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
    //do upload stuff to the server here
        }, to: server)
        .uploadProgress(queue: .main, closure: { progress in
            //Current upload progress of file
            print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { data in
            guard let JSON = data.result.value else { return }
            print("JSON IS \(JSON)")
            //decode the JSON here...
        })
```

On the line where I'm guarding that data.result.value has a value (the JSON response sent from the server), I'm getting a 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context'.

The code to send the JSON object from the server looks like this on the Node.js side:

```
app.post('/createCommunity', upload.single('cameraPhoto'), async function (request, response) {
    // do operations to get required variables
    var returnObject = {
      community_id: id,
      title: title,
      members: members,
      image: imageURL
    }
    response.send(returnObject)
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you could try: `guard let JSON = data.result.value as? [String: Any] else { return }`
 or another specific dictionary structure to help the compiler.

Comment: There is no `result.value` property, unless you've added it yourself.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `responseJSON` is deprecated in recent Alamofire versions. What value are you trying to get?

Comment: @Larme Serverside, I'm just doing a classic Node.js response.send(returnedJSONObject). The 'data' in the completion handler is of some weird AFData type which isn't convertible to data so I don't even know how to extract that JSON object that I want...

Comment: @JonShier See my answer above. I'm sending a JSON object as a response and trying to get at it on the swift side.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine See my answer above. I'm sending a JSON object as a response and trying to get at it on the swift side.

Comment: can you show an example of the JSON object your server is sending as a response to your `upload` request.

Comment: can you explain what type each element is, e.g. `members` seems to be an array of some type. My thinking here, is to create a `decodable` struct for the response.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I have a codable struct called 'Community' on the swift side, I just need to know where/how to decode it in the .responseJSON completion handler, you know? The types of the variables in the struct are community_id (Int), title (String), members ([String]), and image (String).

Comment: could you try this: `AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
 //do upload stuff to the server here
}, to: server)
    .responseDecodable(of: Community.self) { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine This was the answer. Put it in an actual answer instead of a comment and I'll mark it as correct :) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a codable/decodable `Community` struct, try this approach:

```
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in  
    //do upload stuff to the server here 
    }, to: server)  
   .responseDecodable(of: Community.self) { response in 
        debugPrint(response)     
    }
```